# How to tell if text is not in UTF-8 encoding?

Tags: ruby, encoding, utf-8

I know there are gems you can use, but I want a simple way to tell if a text is NOT in UTF-8 encoding.

Currently, this is the method I am using:

```
cd = CharDet.detect(text)
encoding = cd['encoding']
```

the problem is this takes way too long (.75 seconds at times)

Is there a way using regex or some other method to tell if a text is not in UTF-8? I don't care to know what encoding it's in. Just that it's not UTF-8

Comment: The only way to know is to parse it until you find an invalid byte sequence or reach the end of the data. `CharDet` is going to parse it multiple times, comparing it to each known charset until one matches, so that would take extra time (and if the text starts with a known UTF BOM, it doesn't even check the text after the BOM). For what you want to do, use the [`UTF8Prober`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rchardet/CharDet/UTF8Prober) class instead, and see if its [`feed()`](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rchardet/CharDet/UTF8Prober#feed-instance_method) method returns `EFoundIt` or `ENotMe`.

Comment: [This article](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/3-steps-to-fix-encoding-problems-in-ruby/) may be of interest.

Comment: @RemyLebeau any example code on how to use UTF8Prober? Can't find anything online

Comment: I'm not a Ruby developer, but (maybe?) something like this (might need tweaking): `utf8 = UTF8Prober.new()` then `if utf8.feed(text) != EFoundIt ... end` or `if utf8.feed(text) == ENotMe ... end`

Comment: The question is hard to "parse". Bytes that are encoded text use the encoding that the writer chose. If you've lost that information, you could ask,  is the byte sequence compatible with a specific encoding or not. UTF-8 does not emit certain values and doesn't emit certain value sequences. So is the question, "How to tell if the encoded text couldn't have been encoded with UTF-8?"

Comment: @TomBlodget yes thats the question

Comment: [Table 3-7. Well-Formed UTF-8 Byte Sequences](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode10.0.0/ch03.pdf#G7404) from the standard would be a good basis for an algorithm that yields either "possibly UTF-8" or "definitely not UTF-8", much like the UTF8Prober that @RemyLebeau suggests. As for rolling your own, it looked like regex would be a good way to build a state machine per the table. But regex seems to do its own check on the input for UTF-8 well-formedness. (So, `text =~ /^.*$/` and catch the error?)

Comment: What should the result be if a text is *both* in UTF-8 *and* some other encoding?